# Why are there multiple NuGet packages for SpecRun.SpecFlow?

Tags: nuget-package, specflow

And which one should I use?

In NuGet we have:

```
SpecRun.SpecFLow
SpecRun.SpecFLow.2-2-0
SpecRun.SpecFLow.1-9-0
SpecRun.SpecFLow.2-3-0
```

etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package you need depends on the SpecFlow version that you are using.

- SpecRun.SpecFlow.1-9-0 is for SpecFlow 1.9
- SpecRun.SpecFlow.2-2-0 is for SpecFlow 2.2
- SpecRun.SpecFlow.2-3-0 is for SpecFlow 2.3

You see the pattern?

SpecRun.SpecFlow is a meta package that has a dependency to the latest version of SpecFlow.
We are not that happy with this situation, but this is the way, SpecFlow currently handles plugins. We have planned to make this easier in the future.

---

Full disclosure: I am one of the developers of SpecFlow & SpecFlow+ (aka SpecRun)

Comment: Cool, thanks.
So the generic "SpecRun.SpecFlow" package is not needed?
I usually have both e.g.
SpecRun.SpecFlow &
SpecRun.SpecFlow.2-3-0

Comment: I would stick with both, as the SpecRun.SpecFlow.*-*-* will merge in the future in the SpecRun.SpecFlow.

Comment: Thanks SabotageAndi!